# Use of meinem in sentences

Tags: preposition, dative

I am a beginner to Deutsch, preparing for my A1. In the sentence *Ich lade meine Freunde zu meinem Haus ein* (implying I invite my friends to my house), why is it not mein Haus? Is it because zu is a dativ preposition? Or anything similar..? Kindly explain.. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, zu/zum asks for *Dativ*. But your sentence is odd. Nobody would say this (but perhaps in some absurdly specific situation), because "zu meinem Haus" implies that you invite them to come close but do not enter. Real life phrases would be: *Ich lade meine Freunde nach hause ein. Ich lade meine Freunde in mein Haus ein. Ich lade meine Freunde zu meiner Party ein.* (Yes, here "zu" is the established form.)

Answer (score 1):

I am not a native speaker of German but yes - *zu* is a Dativ preposition.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the word 'zu' is a dativ preposition.

[Here a complete list.](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/German/Grammar/Prepositions_and_Postpositions)
Another example would be:

> An Weihnachten fahre ich zu meinem Bruder

Comment: Is it correct to use "zum mein Haus?" if not, what is the usage of 'zum'?

Comment: @SojuTVarghese: `Zum` is short for `zu dem`. So you could say `zum Haus` (`to the house`), but `zum mein` and `zum meinen` are both incorrect.